# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'Equality'

Tags: python, typeerror, sympy, differential-equations

I am getting an error of

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'Equality' at "Jn=(q*E*muN*N_at_0)".
```

How can I perform multiplication of `<class 'sympy.core.relational.Equality'>` with `<class 'float'>`?

```py
import sympy as sp
from sympy import *
import math
x=sp.Symbol('x')
n=sp.Function('n')(x)
p=sp.Function('p')(x)
t=200*10**(-7)
q=1.60217662*10**(-19)
k=1.38065*10**(-23)
T=300.00
Vbi=1
V=0
alpha=5.7*10**4
N0=1.71*10**17
G=alpha*N0
E=(V-Vbi)/t
muN=1
muP=1
Vt=k*T/q
Dn=muN*Vt
Dp=muP*Vt
Nc=2.2*10**(20)
Nv=Nc
Nd=3*10**(19)
Na=10**(18)
Eg=1.55
n_t = Nc*math.exp(-Eg/Vt)
p_0 = Nc*math.exp(-Eg/Vt)
Nsol=sp.Eq(Dn*n.diff(x,x)+(muN*E)*n.diff(x)+G,0)    
Psol=sp.Eq(Dp*p.diff(x,x)-(muP*E)*p.diff(x)+G,0)
ics1={n.subs(x,0):Nd, n.subs(x,t):n_t}
ics2={p.subs(x,0):p_0, p.subs(x,t):Na}
ivN=sp.dsolve(Nsol, ics=ics1)
ivP=sp.dsolve(Psol, ics=ics2)
N_at_0=ivN.subs(x,0)
P_at_0=ivP.subs(x,0)
Jn=(q*E*muN*N_at_0)
Jp=(q*E*muP*P_at_0)
```

Error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-3634a48ae130> in <module>()
     35 N_at_0=ivN.subs(x,0)
     36 P_at_0=ivP.subs(x,0)
---> 37 Jn=(q*E*muN*N_at_0)
     38 Jp=(q*E*muP*P_at_0)
```

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to do symbolic calculations with floating-point constants, as simplifications may not happen due to rounding errors (not errors while rounding, but discrepancies while computing the same value in different ways). Better use symbolic constants and substitute the values in the final result. /// As to your question, it might help to use the `rhs` operator to get the value on the right-hand side, as in `N_at_0.rhs` or earlier in `ivN.rhs.subs(x,0)`.

Comment: It isn't necessary to use `Eq` at all because in sympy `a-b` is generally treated as `a=b` i.e. `a-b=0` in situations where an equation is expected like when calling `dsolve`.

Comment: show us each of the variables in `q, E, muN, N_at_0`

Comment: @OscarBenjamin, skipping the `Eq` doesn't change the result.  `N_at_0` is still a `Eq` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to see intermediate results, especially in `sympy` calculations.  It's easier to read and understand.  Otherwise I have to run the code myself (not always possible).

```
In [4]: n_t = Nc*math.exp(-Eg/Vt)
   ...: p_0 = Nc*math.exp(-Eg/Vt)
In [5]: n_t
Out[5]: 2.0118139286850867e-06

In [6]: Nsol=sp.Eq(Dn*n.diff(x,x)+(muN*E)*n.diff(x)+G,0)
   ...: Psol=sp.Eq(Dp*p.diff(x,x)-(muP*E)*p.diff(x)+G,0) 
In [7]: Nsol
Out[7]: 
                                          2                      
          d                              d                       
- 50000.0⋅──(n(x)) + 0.0258520187368606⋅───(n(x)) + 9.747e+21 = 0
          dx                              2                      
                                        dx                       

In [8]: ics1={n.subs(x,0):Nd, n.subs(x,t):n_t}
   ...: ics2={p.subs(x,0):p_0, p.subs(x,t):Na}
In [9]: ics1
Out[9]: {n(0): 30000000000000000000, n(2.0e-5): 2.0118139286850867e-06}

In [10]: ivN=sp.dsolve(Nsol, ics=ics1)
    ...: ivP=sp.dsolve(Psol, ics=ics2)
In [11]: ivN
Out[11]: 
                                        1934084.9358394⋅x          
n(x) = 1.9494e+17⋅x - 476.291693838697⋅ℯ                  + 3.0e+19

In [12]: N_at_0=ivN.subs(x,0)
    ...: P_at_0=ivP.subs(x,0)
In [13]: N_at_0
Out[13]: n(0) = 3.0e+19

In [14]: type(_)
Out[14]: sympy.core.relational.Equality
```

So `N_at_0` is a `Equality` object - which is what the error complains about:

```
In [15]: Jn=(q*E*muN*N_at_0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-28d29a3734cf> in <module>
----> 1 Jn=(q*E*muN*N_at_0)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'Equality'
```

But we can get the numeric part of the `Eq` with `.rhs`:

```
In [24]: N_at_0.rhs
Out[24]: 3.00000000000000e+19

In [25]: Jn=(q*E*muN*N_at_0.rhs)

In [26]: Jn
Out[26]: -240326.493000000
```